# std::vector reserve being more costly than expected

Tags: c++, memory, vector, stl

So I need to manually handle the memory allocated by an std::vector for efficiency purposes. And I noticed that my program was slower than expected, so I added this idiom everywhere in my code base:

```
const uint new_edges_capacity = mesh.edges.size() + 6;
if(new_edges_capacity > mesh.edges.capacity())
    mesh.edges.reserve(new_edges_capacity * 2);
```

Originally I was simply doing:

```
const uint new_edges_capacity = mesh.edges.size() + 6; 
mesh.edges.reserve(new_edges_capacity * 2);
```

Well, that first snippet is orders of magnitude faster than the second.
I don't understand, the official documentation seems to suggest that reserve should already be doing the same check I am. However, `perf` definitely marks std::reserve as the most expensive operation in my code, and indeed the modification shows that not calling reserve and relying on it to check for allocation is faster.

An example of a function where I am using this pattern:

```
template<typename V>
void HMesh<V>::SplitFace(uint face_id, HMesh<V>& mesh)
{
    mesh.vertex_data.push_back({});
    mesh.verts.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MVert& c = mesh.verts.back();

    const uint new_edges_capacity = mesh.edges.size() + 6;
    if(new_edges_capacity > mesh.edges.capacity())
        mesh.edges.reserve(new_edges_capacity * 2);
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& n00 = mesh.edges.back();
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& n01 = mesh.edges.back();
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& n10 = mesh.edges.back();
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& n11 = mesh.edges.back();
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& n20 = mesh.edges.back();
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& n21 = mesh.edges.back();

    const uint new_faces_capacity = mesh.faces.size() + 2;
    if(new_faces_capacity > mesh.faces.capacity())
        mesh.faces.reserve(new_faces_capacity * 2);
    mesh.faces.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MFace& f1 = mesh.faces.back();
    mesh.faces.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MFace& f2 = mesh.faces.back();

    auto& face = mesh.faces[face_id];

    HMesh<V>::MFace& f0 = face;

    HMesh<V>::MEdge& e0 = face.EdgeD();
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& e1 = face.EdgeD().NextD();
    HMesh<V>::MEdge& e2 = face.EdgeD().PrevD();

    HMesh<V>::MVert& v0 = e0.VertD();
    HMesh<V>::MVert& v1 = e1.VertD();
    HMesh<V>::MVert& v2 = e2.VertD();

    ConnectFace(f0, n00, e0, n10);
    ConnectFace(f1, n11, e1, n21);
    ConnectFace(f2, n20, e2, n01);

    Pair(n00, n01);
    Pair(n10, n11);
    Pair(n20, n21);

    AttachVertices(n00, c, v0);
    AttachVertices(n11, c, v1);
    AttachVertices(n20, c, v2);

    c.Data({
        (v0.Data().position + v1.Data().position + v2.Data().position) / 3.0,
        (v0.Data().uv + v1.Data().uv + v2.Data().uv) / 3.0,
        {0,0,1}
    });
}
```

Comment: Gcc with no optimizations (because of debugging reasons)

Comment: Your first one doubles the size when it's full. Your second one potentially adds 2 elements every time it runs. Your second one does a lot more reserving.

Comment: `reserve` checks if `new_edges_capacity * 2 > capacity()`, but you are checking `new_edges_capacity > capacity()`. Also timings with no optimisations are meaningless

Comment: Timings with linear operations over thousands of data points are not meaningless. Point in case, this change makes the code orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: But I also think your comment was my problem.

Comment: "So I need to manually handle the memory allocated by an std::vector for efficiency purposes." plus "no optimizations (because of debugging reasons)" are directly at odds

Comment: I will enable the optimizations, obviously, right now they are disabled because it makes debugging simpler when I have to step down on GDB. Most of my problems are of numeric nature and it helps not having to worry about the compiler changing the order of my math operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not reimplementing `reserve`, you're reimplementing the resize operation when capacity is exhausted. Problem is, if you do this every time you insert an item, you're resizing every time, making *every* operation `O(n)` (as it has to move all the items from the original backing storage to the new, larger, storage). If you ran this every time, building from an empty `vector`, you'd see a pattern of:

```
Size  Capacity  Reallocation needed?
1     14        Yes
2     16        Yes (16 > 14)
3     18        Yes (18 > 16)
4     20        Yes (20 > 18)
... reallocations continue forever ...
```

and each of those resizes would cause a new allocation, a move of all existing elements, and clean up of the old allocation (with destructors of the moved-from objects firing). You haven't saved *anything*, because you force new allocations every time, in an effort to avoid unnecessary allocations (which is clearly unhelpful).

In the case with the `if` test, since you test against a value half of what you `reserve` if the test fails, it reallocates much less frequently:

```
Size  Capacity  Reallocation needed?
1     14        Yes
2     14        No  (2 + 6 <= 14)
3     14        No  (3 + 6 <= 14)
4     14        No  (4 + 6 <= 14)
5     14        No  (5 + 6 <= 14)
6     14        No  (6 + 6 <= 14)
7     14        No  (7 + 6 <= 14)
8     14        No  (8 + 6 <= 14)
9     30        Yes  (9 + 6 > 14)
... very rare reallocations ...
```

As you can see, your test means *far* less resizing activity.

If you're just trying to guess at how much space you need, don't; let `vector` resize automatically on demand (doubling every time it's *necessary* might save you a little time over the default amortized growth schedule, but it also wastes a lot of memory). `reserve` is for when you know how much space you need; using it over and over is expensive.

Comment: But the documentation says:
`
If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n (or greater).

In all other cases, the function call does not cause a reallocation and the vector capacity is not affected.`

It says no allocation should occur if the capacity does not exceed the limit

Comment: @Makogan: Is the container ever changing size? Without a [MCVE], my assumption is that you're running this before or after insertions into the `vector`, which would mean the new requested capacity is always a little bit larger than the last requested capacity.

Comment: @Makogan: Remember, your test is asking if the new capacity it greater than the current capacity, but it resizes to *twice* that new capacity. The documentation is saying "If you ask for capacity *at all* greater than the current, we have to resize", but your test ensures you only ask for greater capacities when it's *much* greater, dramatically reducing the number of times you need to resize the backing storage.

Comment: @Makogan And look at the "Capacity" in the answer's chart. Every time you are telling it to make a bigger capacity, so every time it has to resize. 16 is bigger than 14. 18 is bigger than 16.

Comment: Yes both in all cases I was reserving twice the amount asked.

Comment: @Makogan: I added tables for with and without the test to make it clear what the difference is, and made it explicit when reallocation was needed, and why.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I should have thought about what I was doing a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reserve *at all*. Just use indices.

```
template<typename V>
void HMesh<V>::SplitFace(uint face_id, HMesh<V>& mesh)
{
    mesh.vertex_data.push_back({});
    mesh.verts.push_back({&mesh});
    HMesh<V>::MVert& c = mesh.verts.back();

    const uint n = mesh.edges.size();
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
    mesh.edges.push_back({&mesh});
 
    auto & n00 = mesh.edges[n + 0];
    auto & n01 = mesh.edges[n + 1];
    auto & n10 = mesh.edges[n + 2];
    auto & n11 = mesh.edges[n + 3];
    auto & n20 = mesh.edges[n + 4];
    auto & n21 = mesh.edges[n + 5];

    const uint f = mesh.faces.size();
    mesh.faces.push_back({&mesh});
    mesh.faces.push_back({&mesh});

    auto& f0 = mesh.faces[face_id];
    auto& f1 = mesh.faces[f + 0];
    auto& f2 = mesh.faces[f + 1];

    auto& e0 = f0.EdgeD();
    auto& e1 = f0.EdgeD().NextD();
    auto& e2 = f0.EdgeD().PrevD();

    auto& v0 = e0.VertD();
    auto& v1 = e1.VertD();
    auto& v2 = e2.VertD();

    ConnectFace(f0, n00, e0, n10);
    ConnectFace(f1, n11, e1, n21);
    ConnectFace(f2, n20, e2, n01);

    Pair(n00, n01);
    Pair(n10, n11);
    Pair(n20, n21);

    AttachVertices(n00, c, v0);
    AttachVertices(n11, c, v1);
    AttachVertices(n20, c, v2);

    c.Data({
        (v0.Data().position + v1.Data().position + v2.Data().position) / 3.0,
        (v0.Data().uv + v1.Data().uv + v2.Data().uv) / 3.0,
        {0,0,1}
    });
}
```